# convert 512-bits in a 256 Hexadecimal table

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer

I have a buffer unsigned char table[512] that I want to convert faster into a table of short int table[256] where every position is compound by to bytes of the table.

I have a camera that give me this buffer that is the table to convert the disparity to the real depth.

```
unsigned char zDtable[512] = {0};
unsigned short int zDTableHexa[256]={0};
.. get the buffer data.....
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        zDTableHexa[i]=zDtable[i*2]<<8 + zDtable[i*2+1];

}
```

these 2 has problem in converting well the values, the bytes are inversed:

```
memcpy(zDTableHexa_ptr,zDtable,256*sizeof( unsigned short int));
unsigned short* zDTableHexa = (unsigned short*)zDtable;
```

Comment: Data is stored in memory in *binary*. Decimal, hexadecimal and also octal are just different ways of presenting that binary data as numbers.

Comment: As for "FAST", have you measured and profiled to learn that this is a bottleneck? A small loop like this will be blindingly fast on just about all modern hardware, you need a very small embedded system for this to be measurable.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
short* zDTableHexa = (short*)zDtable;
```

It simply maps the memory space of char array to an array of shorts. So if the memory looks like this:
(char0),(char1),(char2),(char3)

then it will be reinterpreted to be
(short0 = char0,char1),(short1 = char2,char3)

Beware that such direct reinterpretation depends on endianness and formally allows a sufficiently pedantic compiler to do ungood things, i.e., it's system- and compiler-specific.

Comment: This also depends on the endianness but it uses far less processing time that running through a for loop

Comment: You might want to add an explanation. One line of code alone isn't worth much. Also, your line may not work if `zDtable` is not aligned.

Comment: a) This code won't compile because you're treating arrays like pointers. b) It violates strict aliasing and therefore is UB, even if the architectures alignment would be ok.

Comment: Firstly, an array is a pointer. And how is it causing aliasing?

Comment: @BrandonPiner Nope, it isn't, it just decays often. Just try it, or read the standard (or some questions here or...). Your changed code now won't compile either, it's even more wrong than before. ... About strict aliasing, I didn't say it "causes aliasing", whatever that means. If you don't know what strict aliasing is, please read about it too. It's far too much for a comment here.

Comment: it is not working the same problem as using: memcpy(zDTableHexa_ptr,zDtable,256*sizeof( unsigned short int));